# getent group working, but sshd_config allowgroups does not retrieve appropriate group

Tags: ldap, accounts, kerberos, openldap

I am trying to setup Kerberos MIT authentication with OpenLdap autorisation on Debian Jessie.

Authentication part is working great, as I can login to SSH using my kerberos account.

I even can create user home directory using pam_mkhomedir.so

However, I can't use Ldap posixGroup to allow access to my SSH server :

Here is the output of `getent group`

```
getent group | grep tupac
adminsLinux:*:3000:uid=tupac,ou=people,dc=maytacapac,dc=inc
```

Here is the extract of sshd_config :

```
AllowGroups adminsLinux
```

Here are the log files :

```
sshd[3305]: User tupac from a.b.c.d not allowed because not in any group
sshd[3305]: input_userauth_request: invalid user tupac [preauth]
sshd[3305]: Connection closed by a.b.c.d [preauth]
```

Here is `id tupac` output

```
uid=20003(tupac) gid=20003 groups=20003
```

tupac user is not part of any Unix group, but I want to allow access based on OpenLdap posixGroup. I have thought /etc/nsswitch.conf configuration and getent group resolution would be enough to grant access according to posixGroups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`uid=tupac,ou=people,dc=maytacapac,dc=inc` looks wrong, as most (okay, all except this one) LDAP-provided group memberships I've seen do not include a LDAP DN, and instead just the username, so I would expect to instead see `adminsLinux:*:3000:tupac`.

Comment: +1. also, commas are used to separate usernames for entries in the groups db (whether from `/etc/group` or elsewhere).

Comment: ok thank you thrig; indeed putting uid value for memberUid makes more sense and solved the issue. I however had to reload nscd as well as the erroneous content was cached for a (short) while. Many thanks again